# Python explode multiple columns where some rows are NaN

Tags: python, explode

I am trying to apply the Python explode function to unpack a few columns that are | delimited. Each row will be the same | delimited length (e.g. A will have the same |s as B) but rows can have  different lengths from one another (e.g. row 1 is length 3 and rows 2 is length 2).

There are some rows where there may be an NaN here and there (e.g. A and C) which is causing the following error "columns must have matching element counts"

```
Current data:

A           | B               | C
1 | 2 | 3     app | ban | cor   NaN
4 | 5         dep | exp         NaN
NaN           for | gep         NaN

Expected output:

A | B   | C
1   app   NaN
2   ban   NaN
3   cor   NaN
4   dep   NaN
5   exp   NaN
NaN for   NaN
NaN gep   NaN



cols = ['A','B','C']

for col in cols:
   df_test[col] = df_test[col].str.split('|')
   df_test[col] = df_test[col].fillna({i: [] for i in df_test.index}) #tried replace the NaN with a null list but same error

df_long = df_test.explode(cols)
```

Comment: Could you just replace the nans before? Is nan an expected value or is it messy data?

Comment: I tried replacing them with null lists. It's just that some columns will not always have a value